# How to view source of a form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to scrape a page to get data for web analytics. I'm on an ecommerce site and have made a dummy purchase. There's a transaction ID on the page but the html surrounding it is not ideal for scraping, the id exists in a unclassified  tag with no classes, IDs or other useful attributes of the parent or parents parent.

So, I wnated to view source and ctrl+F the transaction id "123456" and see if it existed anywhere else in the dom.

But, when I view source I get a "confirm form submission" page and don't get to view the html behind the page.

Adding the Javascript tag too in case there's a magical way of searching through all global variables for the value of "123456" anywhere in those variables? If I found the ecommerce data in a global variable object it would be very convenient as opposed to scraping the HTML which, in this case, has few attributes to drill down into

Comment: Use Inspect element instead of "View Source", you can `Ctrl + F` there too. That way you will avoid the "Confirm form submission" message.

Comment: Yes, I tried that already but viewing just the element in this case is not helpful since there's no id or class surrounding it or parents I can scrape. So by viewing source I was going to see if it existed anywhere else such as in a JS object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just save whole page on your disk as HTML file. In Chrome you can just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, select your destination and next edit saved file in some text editor.